# node.js trying to pass variables around like I would in python

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript, I am trying to pass the result of a nested function, down to the rest of the parent function ? maybe?

I have documents in one mongodb collection, and company info in another. So I am trying to pair them up like this part of the code, but it is not doing what I am trying to get done. I think I am clearly missing something about javascript and the way it functions.

I am able to get the list of companies, and log to the console, but I can't do what I am doing at this line

`'name': companies[0]['name'],`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const {Data, Companies} = require('./data.js');


const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();



const dbRoute = 'mongodb://192.168.200.20/matrix';

mongoose.connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));


router.post("/searchData", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("REQ---", req.body.search_obj)
  let answers = []
  let search_query = req.body.search_obj
  let arg_group = [];
  let arg_template = [];
  let arg_object = {}
  for (i in search_query){
    arg_query = {search_text: { $regex: new RegExp(search_query[i]), $options: 'i' }}
    arg_group = arg_group.concat(arg_query)
  }
  arg_template = arg_template.concat(arg_group)
  arg_list = "\"{$and: [" + arg_group + "]}\""
  arg_object['$and'] = arg_template

  Data.find(arg_object, function (err, data){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
      for (i in data) {
        console.log("Resolved to ... : ", data[i]['_id'], data[i]['title']);
        Companies.find({_id: data[i]['_id']})
          .then(companies => {
            console.log("Company Name:")
            console.log("NAME >>>> >>>> ", companies[0]['name']);

          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })

        search_reply = {
          '_id': data[i]['_id'],
          'title': data[i]['title'],
          'url': data[i]['url'],
          'release_date': data[i]['release_date'],
          'document_date': data[i]['document_date'],
          'name': companies[0]['name'],
        }
        answers[i] = search_reply

    }

      console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
      console.log("ANSWERS", answers)
      console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
      return res.json(answers);
    }
  })

});



router.post('/updateData', (req, res) => {
  const { id, update } = req.body;
  Data.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, (err) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});


router.delete('/deleteData', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  Data.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

router.post('/putData', (req, res) => {
  let data = new Data();

  const { id, message } = req.body;

  if ((!id && id !== 0) || !message) {
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      error: 'INVALID INPUTS',
    });
  }
  data.message = message;
  data.id = id;
  data.save((err) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I went through a few changes based on some of the suggestionsin it, but I could not make any of them work any better. I think it comes from a shallow understanding of what JavaScript does :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either move all of your `search_reply` logic inside promise then callback. The other solution which could be easier is to use async/await for handling Promises. Let's first assume that your parent function is called `getSearchResults`, so based on that your code would look like:

```js
try {
    const data = await Data.find(arg_object);
    console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
    for (const answer in data) {
        console.log("Resolved to ... : ", answer['_id'], answer['title']);
        const companies = await Companies.find({ _id: answer['_id'] });

        search_reply = {
            '_id': answer['_id'],
            'title': answer['title'],
            'url': answer['url'],
            'release_date': answer['release_date'],
            'document_date': answer['document_date'],
            'name': companies[0]['name'],
        }
        answers.push(search_reply);
    }

    console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
    console.log("ANSWERS", answers)
    console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

**Updates:**
This updated piece of code should replace DB access code inside `router.post("/searchData", (req, res, next) => {...}` endpoint. Starting from `Data.find(arg_object, function(err, data) {...}`

Fixed answers to match the for .. in loop, instead of using index.

It's using async/await for handling promises and try/catch for handling errors

Comment: now the full code is there is the solution any different ? I tried what you said, but in the `return` at the bottom, it returns nothing.

Comment: Can't believe I am struggling so hard with this, have watched videos on promises and callbacks, and kind of get the gist of it. but I can't implement it in this file, so I must have something else out-of-whack...

Comment: anyone else care to have a crack at this ... I am stumped, every tutorial I read, or video, they are just not quite the same as my case ... but a more skilled operator might see it straight away ?

Comment: I've used the little detailed code you've supplied to show you how to do it, for the return you can simply just return `res.json(answers)`.
I'll modify the code, my suggested solution is shorter and uses ES6 new async/await

Comment: Code updated supposing that this piece of code would be executed inside a middleware and would return the answers as JSON. Could you at least try it and let me know? It's shorter, more modern solution and it was first

Comment: Fair enough, I put it into service, and had to make a few small adjustments, `const companies = await Companies.find({_id: data[answer]['_id']});` but yes it works, thanks... If it matters who was first with a workable solution, then yes my original pick of @traynor 's answer would be correct. But in the interest of neater more correct code, this one is the winner

Comment: Thanks Brett for testing the suggested solution

Comment: FWIW, `await Companies.find` is a slower solution than `for` loop..

Comment: Can you explain more? What's the relation between MongoDB `find()` function and `for` loop in the code provided? Thanks

Comment: every iteration in the `for..in` loop here will pause the code until `await Companies.find` is finished, unlike the `for` loop + callback (which actually might be a better option in this case, with refactoring maybe using `Promise.all`)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that node.js runs asynchronously, so you return results before `Companies.find` is done. so you should return results only when everything is finished, which means you need to send results from `Companies.find`.

since you're iterating over many results, a quick and dirty way (the whole code should be rewritten otherwise) to know when everything is done is to add a counter and then return when the last loop is done (replace `for..in` loop with `for` loop to get a numeric index)

try this:

```
  Data.find(arg_object, function (err, data){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log("Resolved to ... : ", data[i]['_id'], data[i]['title']);
        Companies.find({_id: data[i]['_id']})
          .then(companies => {
            console.log("Company Name:")
            console.log("NAME >>>> >>>> ", companies[0]['name']);


           let search_reply = {
              '_id': data[i]['_id'],
              'title': data[i]['title'],
              'url': data[i]['url'],
              'release_date': data[i]['release_date'],
              'document_date': data[i]['document_date'],
              'name': companies[0]['name'],
            }
            answers.push(search_reply)

            if(i+1==data.length) {
                  console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
                  console.log("ANSWERS", answers)
                  console.log("LENGTH", data.length)
                  return res.json(answers);
            }

          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })

    }
      
    }
  })
```

Comment: very close, in the logging I am getting a couple of `<1 empty item>` in the `console.log("ANSWERS", answers)`, then when that is finished printing to console, I get a belated `NAME >>>>> etc" with the "empty" ones ?? I will investigate further

Comment: @Brett did you replace the for loop? try the new code

Comment: yes, I replaced it with yours,

Comment: @Brett did it work now? I also added `.push` to the `answers`, that's probably what's causing empty elements..

Comment: Boom, that did it, thank you **SO** much ... I have spent to long trying to solve this

Comment: @Brett great. that code now needs some heavy refactoring. here's a link that explains the problem with this code: [Asynchronous flow control](https://nodejs.dev/learn/asynchronous-flow-control), and how it might be changed: [Modern Asynchronous JavaScript with Async and Await](https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await)

Comment: thanks I will check that out ... it's been a big week learning and building in a language I don't know :)